# сделал телеграм боте функцию бана по урока хауди хо, но выскакивает ошибка, что делать?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

вот код:

```
import config
import logging
import filters

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

from filters import IsAdminFilter

# log level
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# bot init
bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# activete filters
dp.filters_factory.bind(IsAdminFilter)

# ban command (admins only!)
@dp.message_handler(is_admin=True, commands=["бан"], commands_prefix="!/")
async def cmd_ban(message: types.Message):
    if not message.reply_to_message:
        await message.reply("эта команда, чтоб банить даунов")
        return

    
    await message.bot.kick_chat_member(chat_id=config.GROUP_ID, user_id=message.reply_to_message.from_user.id)
   
    await message.reply_to_message.reply("этот даун забанен))")

# remove new user joined messages
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"])
async def on_user_joined(message: types.Message):
    await message.delete()

# echo
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.text)

# run long-polling
if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

вот ошибка:

```
line 24
    return
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

менял 24 строку как мог, ничего не помогает

Comment: думаю вопрос стоит адресовать хауди хо

Comment: В приложенном коде на 25 строчке не хватает таба, возможно на это ругается

Comment: текст ошибки понятен?

Comment: Для начала перестать смотреть хауди хо

Answer (score 0):

Проблема довольно проста - в одной строчке идут вместе табы и пробелы.
Питон очень не любит, когда так делают)

В текстовом редакторе выделите пустое пространство перед `return` в 24 строке, посмотрите, не соседствуют ли там пробелы и таб. Замените таб пробелами или наоборот, это решит проблему.